# Add hours from input , Datetime/Timedelta (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to make a script to go to a website and enter in a time in a 24 hour format.
I'm using the pyautogui module to perform the web tasks, and Datetime/Timedelta for the time.

I have a big problem, and it's really bugging me.
I want to add the number that the user inputs to the current time, the user input will be in hours. `E.G: user enters a 5, the script will add 5 hours to the current time`.

Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

xtime = input("enter a number to add in hours: ")

    pyautogui.moveTo(833, 566, 1)
    pyautogui.click()
    datetime.format = '%HH:%MM'
    now + timedelta(hours=xtime)
    new_time = now + timedelta(xtime)
    pyautogui.typewrite(new_time)
    pyautogui.press('enter')
```

Please, if someone knows how I could do this, let me know. I've spent days trying this and nothing works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to automate a task on a website, a module like pyautogui that controls your mouse or keyboard is not a good solution.
Instead, I recommend you to use a module that takes control of your browser like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Then, to convert an integer into hours and add it to an existing time, you can do like this

```py
import time

now = time.time()

add = int(input("The number of hours you want to add : ")) * 3600

format_24h = time.strftime("%HH:%MM", time.localtime(now + add))
```

Comment: This works, but it's typing this "H20:M20" (this is an example). It's adding the H and M as well as the time, how can I stop this?

Comment: Just remove one of the two "H" and one of the two "M" in the string at `time.strftime`